# Shoutout to this community for its good work!

Tags: discussion

I didn't do my part and asked a good question on the wrong subsite of StackExchange; it belonged to [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208209/how-to-choose-the-appearance-of-the-gmail-app).

Somebody migrated the post, I think a user named Alex, who was the user with the highest reputation to interact with my post.

In any case, thank you, that's how helping others work, cheers!